# Flutter Video_Player package disposing videos when I pull down Notification Center on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart

I've been having this issue for a long time now, and honestly I'm just surprised no one has mentioned it anywhere online!

I'm using the video player package in Flutter, and every time I either quit the app or pull down the notification or control centre, if the videos are **PAUSED** then they are replaced with a white screen, some of them also disappear. I have to click on that white screen for them to continue playing! I think the videos are being disposed, I'm not sure since when I click on the video to resume playing, it continues playing from where it was paused.

This is the only thing keeping me from release using flutter. It only happens on IOS, and I've tested it on 4 different iPhones ranging from iPhone 8 to 10 to 11 pro.

No reason to post any code since following the example on Video_Player package page gives me the same issue.

Any one was able to go around that ?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Change flutter channels from stable to dev and the issue should be resolved. Hopefully we'll have it on the stable channel soon.